# Create Index using Liquibase (INCLUDE COLUMN)

Tags: sql, sql-server, liquibase

I want to create an INDEX on my MSSQL DB and the index should looks like :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [table] ON [status] ([date]) INCLUDE ([id], [status]) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

I found that with liquibase "sql" tag option we can execute the SQL script and i applied the same in my liquibase script:

```
<changeSet  author="author"  id="15">  
    <sql  dbms="mssql"  schemaName="${SCHEMA_NAME}"
            endDelimiter="\nGO"  
            splitStatements="true"  
            stripComments="true">CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [table] ON [status] ([date]) INCLUDE ([id], [status]) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
     </sql>  
</changeSet>
```

But, the problem is the above changeset working only with the enterprise DB.

```
Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.
```

Anybody, know how i can achieve the same task use liquibase changeset CREATEINDEX option.

Comment: As it is quite common with MS SQL Server, the error message you receive from the database engine contains both the explanation and the workaround.

Comment: @RogerWolf I understood about the problem that it can be only possible in Enterprise edition, but i am not getting what can be work around ?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message states,

> Online index operations can only be performed in Enterprise edition of
> SQL Server.

In order to make it work, all you need to do is to drop the `ONLINE` clause from your `create index` statement:

```sql
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [table] ON [status] ([date]) INCLUDE ([id], [status]);
```

This will work on any edition. At the same time, if you want to be able to utilise the online index creation and rebuild when edition allows it, you can check the version of the Database Engine your app connects to, and then optionally add supported clauses, such as `online` in this case.

In your example, online index rebuild is [only available in Enterprise edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-version-15), however Development and Evaluation editions are functionally equivalent to it, so online index operations are available in them, too.

Here is the way to determine the functional level of your SQL Server instance:

```sql
select serverproperty('EngineEdition');
```

This gives you the actual capabilities of your instance, regardless of the licensing. By comparing the result of this query with [documented values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/serverproperty-transact-sql) it can return, you can make a decision on which options it supports, and include suitable parts to your query before executing it.

Comment: The server property can be used in Liquibase to create a pre-condition for the changeset and run different CREATE INDEX statements based on the edition

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I'm not familiar with Liquibase, so I just described the most generic approach, independent of any platform specifics. If Liquibase does it, well, that's even easier.